# Не получается запустить проект expo с помощью npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
  my-project@1.0.0 start /home/just/my-project
  expo start
 
 (node:3103) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
 /home/just/my-project/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/rest/client.js:26
     name = "ApiV2Error";
          ^
 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
     at Object.<anonymous (/home/just/my-project/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/getExpoGoIntermediateCertificate.js:7:15)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) (node:3103)
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
 without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
 with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:3103) [DEP0018]
 DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
 the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:3103)
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
 /home/just/my-project/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/rest/client.js:26
     name = "ApiV2Error";
          ^
 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
     at Object.<anonymous (/home/just/my-project/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/getExpoGoIntermediateCertificate.js:7:15)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) (node:3103)
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
 without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
 with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: В файле `client.js:26` происходит ошибка, которую вы не перехватывете. Видимо это асинхронная функция или промис, у которой отсутствует `.catch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта ошибка указывает на проблему с синтаксисом в файле **client.js**, который находится в пакете **@expo/cli**.

Возможно, проблема связана с версией **Node.js**, которую вы используете. Попробуйте проверить, установлена ли на вашем компьютере последняя версия **Node.js**. Если у вас установлена старая версия, попробуйте обновить ее до последней версии.

Если обновление **Node.js** не помогло, попробуйте выполнить следующие шаги:

Удалите папку **node_modules** из своего проекта.

Очистите кэш **NPM**, запустив команду `npm cache clean`.

Установите зависимости заново, запустив команду `npm install`.

Попробуйте запустить проект снова, используя команду `npm start`.

Если эти шаги не решат проблему, попробуйте обновить пакет **@expo/cli** до последней версии, используя команду `npm update @expo/cli`.

Comment: ща попробую....

Comment: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)

Comment: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Comment: теперь выбило вот это

Comment: @user543786 Ошибка, **Cannot find module 'semver'** говорит о том, что у вас не установлен этот модуль... `npm i` в помощь

Comment: так он её выбивает при любой команде

Comment: у вас вон ошибка **Error: Cannot find module 'semver'**. Попробуйте установить semver ```npm install semver```

Comment: всё заработало спасибо, надо было чере sudo просто